# fcase to multiple outputs

Tags: r, data.table, case

Assume the following table:

```
data <- data.table(dummy=1:10)
```

I know that you can do the following things:

```
data[dummy < 5, c("test1", "test2") := list("Yes", 1)]
```

and:

```
data[, test1 := fcase(dummy < 5, "Yes")]
data[, test2 := fcase(dummy < 5, 1)]
```

I am trying to combine these into one like so:

```
data[, c("test1", "test2") := fcase(dummy < 5, list("Yes", 1))]
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error in fcase(dummy < 5, list("Yes", 1)) : 
  Length of output value #2 must either be 1 or length of logical condition.
```

I need to go through multiple filters so it makes sense to use `fcase`. I can always resort to using the first solution for each filter like so:

```
data[dummy < 5, c("test1", "test2") := list("Yes", 1)]
data[dummy > 7, c("test1", "test2") := list("No", 0)]
data[between(dummy, 5, 7), c("test1", "test2") := list("Maybe", NA)]
```

but I am wondering if there isn't something more possible. There's also the solution of creating a table with each combination of `test1` and `test2` and merge this table with the data table after doing an `fcase` for only `test1` like so:

```
tests <- data.table(test1 = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"),
                    test2 = c(1, 0, NA))

data[, test1 := fcase(dummy < 5, "Yes",
                      dummy > 7, "No",
                      between(dummy, 5, 7), NA_character_)]
merge(data, tests, by = "test1", all.x = T, sort = F)
```

But this seems inefficient for a large and complex datatable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `rbindlist`:

```
data[, c("test1", "test2") := rbindlist(fcase(dummy < 5, .(.("Yes", 1)),
                                              dummy > 7, .(.("No", 0)),
                                              default = .(.("Maybe", NA))))]
data
#>     dummy test1 test2
#>  1:     1   Yes     1
#>  2:     2   Yes     1
#>  3:     3   Yes     1
#>  4:     4   Yes     1
#>  5:     5 Maybe    NA
#>  6:     6 Maybe    NA
#>  7:     7 Maybe    NA
#>  8:     8    No     0
#>  9:     9    No     0
#> 10:    10    No     0
```

`do.call` will let you put your `fcase` conditions into a list and the values in another list of nested lists:

```
data[, c("test1", "test2") := rbindlist(do.call(fcase, rbind(.(dummy < 5, dummy <= 7, dummy > 7),
                                                             .(.(.("Yes", 1)), .(.("Maybe", NA)), .(.("No", 0))))))]
```

Or with the `tests` example:

```
tests <- data.table(test1 = c("Yes", "Maybe", "No"),
                    test2 = c(1, NA, 0))
tests[, val := .(.(.(.SD))), by = 1:nrow(tests)]
data[, c("test1", "test2") := rbindlist(do.call(fcase, rbind(.(dummy < 5, dummy <= 7, dummy > 7), tests$val)))]
```

Comment: Hi @jblood94, Great answer, both elegant and enlightening. Thanks for sharing. Cheers.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @jblood94, in the same vein, do you know if there is a way to put also the different tests in a list and the values in another list. Even though I know the syntax I am proposing is wrong, to be clear, write something like this: `rbindlist(fcase(.(dummy < 5, dummy > 7), .(.("Yes", 1)), .(.("No", 0))), default = .(.("Maybe", NA))))]` . Thank you in advance for your feedback. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery I added a couple examples along the lines of your question-comment.

Comment: Thank you so much @jblood94. Your examples lead me to ask you one last question! Following your last example, I tried to handle the `cases` as you handled the `tests` but R returns the following error message: `Error in (function (..., default = NA) : Argument #1 must be logical. ` Here's what I did: `cases <- data.table(Ncases = c("dummy < 5", "dummy <= 7", "dummy > 7"))`, then `cases[, val := .(.(.(. SD))), by = 1:nrow(cases)]` and finally `data[, c("test1", "test2") := rbindlist(do.call(fcase, rbind(.(as.list(cases$val)), as.list(tests$val))))]` Thank you in advance for your help. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery `fcase` won't accept strings for the `when` arguments. You could work around that by making `Ncases` a vector of expressions. This doesn't fit with the OP's question, so I'd rather not further clutter my answer. I suggest creating a new question and referencing this one--maybe someone will come up with a better way than what I'm thinking.

Comment: O.K. Thank you very much @jblood94 for your comment. I'll try to explore the path you give me and if I fail (which is very likely!), I'll post a new question with a link to this one, as you suggest. Cheers.